# Extracting Terms of a Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given a polynomial $P(x)$, can you find the coefficients of $P$ by taking values of $P(k)$ for finitely many arbitrary values $k$? If so, what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can have a look at Lagrange interpolating polynomials

Comment: Look up Vandermonde approach to interpolation.

Comment: @copper.hat What if I specifically want a single term? Can I find it without having to evaluate the whole polynomial?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton's_series for instance

Comment: What is known about the polynomial?  Is its degree known? Or any maximum bound for its coefficients? Can the values $k$ be chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the polynomial provided to you? From the way you have framed your question, it looks like it is not given in the standard coefficients form $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$.

The alternate representations $f(x)$ could be are:

1. **Factor form**: The polynomial is given as

$$f(x) = a(x - r_0)(x - r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$$

In this case, you can multiply the terms and then collect the coefficients of each term. If you want only the $k$-th term, you take $k$ combinations of the factors and keep track of the sum of the coefficients.

2. **Set of $n+1$ points**, $\{(x, f(x))\}$:

In this case you can interpolate the points using Lagrange interpolation or Newton's interpolation (forward or backward difference methods) and then compute the coefficients. There is a closed form formula for the coefficient of the $k$-th term in Newton's interpolation.

3. **Black box method:**

In this case you are only given evaluations of the polynomial at various $x$ coordinates. This is similar to #2 above which can be solved using interpolation in the general case where your polynomial coefficients are from the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ or any field $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ etc.,)

**Special case, $f(x)$ with integer coefficients:** However, if we restrict to polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and the polynomials have a special form i.e., $a_i \ge 0$ where $h(f) = \max_i |a_i|$ is the classical height of the polynomial, just two evaluations of $f(x)$ are sufficient. We could take any $b > f(1) \ge h(f)$ and evaluate $f(b)$. For instance, $b = f(1) + 1$ and $c = f(b)$.

This gives $$c = f(b) = a_0 + a_1 b + a_2 b^2 + \cdots + a_n b^n.$$ This is the base-$b$ representation of $c$.

For example: let $f(x) = 5x^2 + 2x + 1$. We have $h(f) = 5$. Therefore, we choose $b = h(f) + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6$ and ask for the evaluation $c = f(6) = 193$.

Given $(b, f(b)) = (6, 193)$, we compute the base-$6$ representation of $c$

$$193_{10} = 5(6^2) + 2(6) + 1 = (5:2:1)_6$$

As we can see the digits are the coefficients of $f(x)$. Instead of $b = h(f) + 1$, we can use any value greater than the height of the polynomial. For eg: $b = f(1) + 1$. Therefore, just 2 evaluations are sufficient.

This is called "The perplexing polynomial puzzle". See Richmond, B. [On a Perplexing Polynomial Puzzle](http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/%7En3parikh/On%20a%20Perplexing%20Polynomial%20Puzzle.pdf) for additional results that extends this to negative integer coefficients.

**The gist:** If $-b \le a_i \le +b$ then $f(2b+1)$ is sufficient to recover the $a_i$ uniquely. Of course, you need the bound $b$ for this. The linked paper gives the algorithm to compute the coefficients, $a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Remember finding straight line equations? You needed two points. Parabolas need three.
In general, you will need n + 1 points for a polynomial of degree n, if you know nothing more about the polynomial than its degree.

The method would be setting up your degree n polynomial with n + 1 unknown coefficients. Substitute in each k value you are using and its corresponding P(k) value to get n+1 linear equations for your n+1 coefficients and solve. They are guaranteed independent. Should you have the choice, I’d suggest using $k = 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, … $ for simplicity of calculations.

But this begs the question of how you will find the points without having the polynomials equation? If you have a graph, fine, so long as you know the degree, which isn’t always obvious over a limited domain (which is the case for a standard graph on an x-y cartesian plane). If you do have the graph, then any turning points  and inflection points you can see can provide 2 or more equations each, by taking into account the requirements of their derivatives, in addition to just their co-ordinates. Lots of other information can be used too, eg if the polynomial is odd or even, every second co-efficient is zero.

If you have neither the equation, nor a graph, and you are just given n+1 points themselves, then just use what you have to make a degree n polynomial, as above. You’ll always find one, by the linear independence. If you have a large table of values instead, perhaps the polynomials degree is less than that suggested by the number of points, in which case you wont need all of them (eg if you had twenty co-ordinate pairs in your table that were based off a simple parabola). Again, if you knew the degree to be n, just picking n + 1 points will be enough.  If you don’t know the degree, it would be best to perhaps graph them first, try to surmise the degree, solve for that (maybe chuck in a couple extra degrees just in case, if you go too low you need to start over, unless you were taking good records of the equation operations performed) then check that the remaining points all fit your equation. Alternatively, if the points provided are evenly spaced, take successive differences between consecutive values until you are left with the same values. The number of times you had to do this is your degree. (Think of a linear graphs table over integers. After taking the differences each will have been equal to the gradient *m*. You’d do this twice for a quadratic). If they aren’t evenly spaced you can still do something like this, dividing each difference by the distance between k’s, but im tiring of the impossible game of exhausting all possibilities now. Get back if your answer is not included yet ;)

Finally, if you are working from a large table of values, you can never really know the degree unless it was given. Even if your table had the points (n,n) for n from 1 to 1000, it may not be y=x, as for k=1/2 the polynomial may have had value -1, for instance. So, in that sense, without the degree it is not possible to find “the true” polynomial, it will always just be one of infinitely many possible.

Comment: I realize that I didn't word the question properly, but assuming I already know the degree of the polynomial, and I can calculate P(x) for all values of x, how can I find a single term (such as the coefficient of x^2) without having to find the entire polynomial from interpolation?

Comment: If you want a specific *coefficient*, you can estimate it by just check the behaviour near x=0, judiciously using at least the n+1 closest points available for the coefficient of $x^n$.  Since theres no “true” underlying  polynomial without knowing the degree, I don’t see anything wrong with estimating them in that sense. But it depends on the broader context of the problem. Eg, If you are using data from an experiment it should work just fine.

Comment: Generally, if you can take successive differences twice around zero and graph these (you must divide by the distance between ks this time) the y intercept of this graph will be your x squared coefficient. Recall that after taking two derivatives of the n degree polynomial *P’’(x)*  and evaluating at zero, it will equal your coefficient a2. Theres also the small problem of ensuring the graph doesn’t vary too much between your k values. Check that your estimate doesn’t change too much after halving the distances. If you want exact, you’ll have to solve the whole n+1 equations.

Comment: @vvg Thats a beautiful method for the integer coefficients case, which I hadn’t seen before, thank you.  
To Hanson Bai perhaps you could fill everyone in on the entire problem you are presented with so someone can provide a solution as elegantly tailored to it as the integer coefficients method vvg provided :)